# javascript looping (use foreach or each)

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, jquery

Can this code change into loop in javascript?
Thanks for helping Im new learner to javascript!

html:

```
<div class="uploadBox"><input id="files3" class="upload" style="position:absolute;" placeholder="Upload Photo"/><input type="file" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:44px;opacity:0;" id="selector3"/></div>
<div id="checkBox3" class="checkBox"><img src="images/check.png"></div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("selector1").addEventListener("change",function(){
    document.getElementById("files1").value=
        document.getElementById("selector1").files[0].name;
    $('#checkBox1').css({'display': 'block'});
});

document.getElementById("selector2").addEventListener("change",function(){
    document.getElementById("files2").value=
        document.getElementById("selector2").files[0].name;
    $('#checkBox2').css({'display': 'block'});
});

document.getElementById("selector3").addEventListener("change",function(){
    document.getElementById("files3").value=
        document.getElementById("selector3").files[0].name;
    $('#checkBox3').css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

Comment: We need to see your html code also. You have jQuery in your code, jQUery has a `.each()` method also...

Comment: is there a parent div to those 2 divs?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("selector" + i).addEventListener("change",function(){
        document.getElementById("files" + i).value=
            document.getElementById("selector" +i).files[0].name;
        $('#checkBox' + i).css({'display': 'block'});
    });
}
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer

Comment: In my code, after i choose the file, it will show the filename at the input box, but this didnt show the filename in inputbox

Answer (score 0):

//i have used 3 you can give the no of times you want

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById("selector"+i.toString()).addEventListener("change",function(){
    document.getElementById("files"+i.toString()).value=
        document.getElementById("selector"+i.toString()).files[0].name;
    $('#checkBox'+i.toString()).css({'display': 'block'});
});
}
```

Comment: In the code, after i choose the file, it will show the filename at the input box, but this didnt show the filename in inputbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[id^=selector]').each(function(){
    this.parent().next('div[class="checkBox"]').css({'display': 'block'});
    this.prev().val(this.files[0].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic: use index of the loop to concatenate a selector (don't forget the closures!).

And it is better not to mix up jQuery and JavaScript for more readability:

```
var n = 3
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    $("selector" + i).on("change", (function (i) {
        return function () {
            $("files" + i).val($("selector" + i).get(0).files[0].name);
            $("#checkBox" + i).css({
                "display": "block"
            });
        }
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: In my code, after i choose the file, it will show the filename at the input box, but this didnt show the filename in inputbox